# Different methods for interacting with Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am sending interactions from Fragment to Activity via interface like so:

MainActivity:

```
var mFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(object : Communicator {
    override fun onNextFragment() {
        doSomeStuff()
    }
})
```

Fragment:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mListener: Communicator

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false)
        view.buttonTest.setOnClickListener {
            mListener.onNextFragment()
        }
        
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(communicator: Communicator) =
            SummaryFragment().apply {
                mListener = communicator
            }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
interface Communicator {
    fun onNextFragment()
}
```

But there is other option, declare function doSomeStuff() as public and call from fragment:

```
(activity as MainActivity).doSomeStuff()
```

And also will work. So what is the advantage and disadvantage of both approaches?

Comment: one thing to note in the scenario where the `Communicator` instance is passed as an argument to the `SummaryFragment`'s static factory method... if that fragment is not a retained instance and happens to undergo a configuration change (e.g. screen rotation), the newly created instance will have a null `Communicator` reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my thought about each approach:

**Define a public function**

Advantage:

- Simple code, no need to write extra code such as interface, implement from activity, do typecast before calling a method from the fragment.

Disadvantage:

- A public function means it can be called from anywhere in the application. So it can cause some unexpected scenarios in case you call it from another place by your mistake.
- To call this function from a fragment, it needs to know the activity to do typecast, which means the fragment depends on activity to do something. It makes the fragment less reusable because whenever you want to reuse this fragment, you need to include the activity as well.

**Using interface**

Advantage:

- Fragment doesn't need to know the activity, it just needs to check whether or not the host activity (the activity that attaches itseft) implements the interface. The fragment just depends on the interface, you can reuse this fragment from many places in the application or other apps.
- When initiating the fragment, you don't need to pass the activity as listener via constructor or factory method in your case (this helps you avoid several potential runtime errors with your apps, such as when users rotate devices or the app killed by the system, because in these cases, the listener will be null and might crash your app). You just set it inside `onAttach` method, like the below example.

Disadvantage:

- More code, you must write extra code such as to define an interface, implement from activity, do typecast from the fragment.

**Example**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mListener: Communicator

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is Communicator) {
            mListener = context
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, there are other approaches to interact between activity and fragment by using.

- [LiveDate](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)